# TPA3110 noise problem

Tags: amplifier, audio, noise

There is noise emanating from each of my two TPA3110 modules([this board](https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/1005004438146103.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4d6c51d4LbRKSU&algo_pvid=f8c0eeb2-dc01-447a-aba5-bf769e0f8ac2&algo_exp_id=f8c0eeb2-dc01-447a-aba5-bf769e0f8ac2-1&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000029181686078%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21VND%21%2121026.0%21%21%214906.0%21%21%402103143616572976860116310e6ad3%2112000029181686078%21sea) & [this board](https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/1005001636453856.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4d6c51d4LbRKSU&algo_pvid=f8c0eeb2-dc01-447a-aba5-bf769e0f8ac2&algo_exp_id=f8c0eeb2-dc01-447a-aba5-bf769e0f8ac2-38&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000016918497233%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21VND%21%2126634.0%21%21%21%21%21%402103143616572976860116310e6ad3%2112000016918497233%21sea).) Even though the noise was not excessively loud, if I put my ear close to the speaker driver, I could still hear it. At night, the noise level is somewhat loud. I use a buck converter and a 12V power source to supply 8.4V to the amplifier. This problem still exists even with 12V.  I want the speaker to be completely silent. How can I fix the problem?

[image]

The TPA3110 has this issue both when I attach my Bluetooth module and when I leave it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

1 - B0505LS-1W - DC/DC converter,
2 - separate DC for BT,
or BT module - trash.

Comment: Can you expand this answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/353639)